# Ruby regular expression: distinguishing between iOS Safari & iOS Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, user-agent

Per the following documentation: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/user-agent

Here is Chrome for iOS UA String:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/534.46.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/19.0.1084.60 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3
```

And here is Safari for iOS UA String:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543 Safari/419.3
```

As best as I can tell the difference going forward will be that Chrome includes "CriOS". I want to be able to distinguish between these two browsers and so set about doing that using a regular expression.

Using:

```
/Gecko\) (?!CriOS)/
```

I'm able to do that but am paranoid as I am not including iPhone in the expression (perhaps this will also trigger on Android, etc.)

I want to write the following regular expression that returns a match when:

1. The string contains "iPhone"
2. The string does not contain "CriOS"

How would I go about doing that?

FYI I've been using rubular for testing reg exp which has been awesome http://rubular.com/

Comment: There's chrome on iOS? Crap, I don't even know if I knew that.

Comment: Just came out a couple of weeks ago :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it :

```
iPhone(?!.*?CriOS)
```

`iPhone` matches any occurence of that word. It then uses a negative lookahead from the `iPhone` match. `.*?CriOS` matches any/all characters until it finds `CriOS`. The `(?!expr)` is a negative lookahead. If the expression is false then what comes before it (`Iphone`) will match, otherwise it won't.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'm new to regex. Do you mind explaining what the syntax above says?

Comment: Hopefully that helps a little.

Comment: you should mark this as the answer if it works, so it can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

For more complete details out of the iPhone Safari string, try:

```
'Mozilla/(\d+(?:\.?\d+)*) \(([\w\s\;]+?)\) AppleWebKit/(\d+(?:.?\d+)*) \([\w\s\,]*\) Version/(\d+(?:.?\d+)*) Safari/(\d+(?:.?\d+)*)'
```

You can now obviously adapt if for Chrome as well...